# iOS - Disable or editing animations of CATextLayer

Tags: ios, xcode, catextlayer

I working with a CATextLayer var and when try to increase the font or type something in this string there is an animation effect with these actions , How can I edit or disable the animation of CATextLayer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting the actions dictionary on the layer to return [NSNull null] as an animation for the appropriate key. for example :

```
   NSDictionary *newActions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNull null], @"contents", nil];
    normalTextLayer_.actions = newActions;
    [newActions release];
```

o disable fade in / out animations I believe the `contents` key is the one you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
// Make changes to the text layer here...
[CATransaction setDisableActions:NO];
```

Comment: thank you but this code disable all of animations , Momeks's code works fine for me .....  How can I change the animations ? I mean set other effects